# How can I do SQL column mappings ignoring missing columns?

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, columnmappings

I am doing bulkcopy from one table to another using the following:

```
bulk.DestinationTableName = reader["Tablename"].ToString();

foreach (DataColumn col in sourceTable.Columns)
{
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
}
```

But the issue is that the first parameter, the source, has a column that is not in the destination.

How can I ignore that mapping if it doesn't exist in the destination?

I have tried checking if the column exists in the destination. But this is very slow as the source table has about 50 columns.

How can I not map the column if it's not in the destination?

Comment: "this is very slow as the source table has about 50 columns." I can't see why that would be slow. What code are you using to do that? You probably just need a `select name from sys.columns where ...`

Comment: isnt there an option whereby the mapping does the check and if it doesnt exists then ignore it ?

Comment: Don't think so.